# Using OpenGL extension in .fsh shader file for SKShader / iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, glsl

In my iOS application I have a shader file `TestShader.fsh` with `GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch` extension:

```
#extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch : require
void main() {
     lowp vec4 destColor = gl_LastFragData[0];
     ...
}
```

According to [apple-ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH7-SW23) I can use the extension to grab destination color. Then I use the shader as

```
spriteNode.shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "TestShader.fsh")
```

However the shader source fails to compile with output

```
error: invalid preprocessing directive
#extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch : require

error: use of undeclared identifier 'gl_LastFragData'
lowp vec4 destColor = gl_LastFragData[0];
```

Without the extension the shader is loaded successfully. So my question is - what is correct way to include OpenGL extension in shader file for iOS app? If it's matter, I'm running on iPhone SE, iOS11, Xcode 9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated at 
[apple forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/94345)
and [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skshader)

> SKShader does not support OpenGL Extensions

-_-